# r RVEST Scraping of URL Related Data no Longer working

Tags: r, web-scraping

In R, I am using the rvest package to scrape player data off the below url
"https://www.covers.com/sport/basketball/nba/teams/main/boston-celtics/2022-2023/roster"

On this page, there are many urls and I want to focus on getting all the player specific urls (and then storing them).  Example is:
"https://www.covers.com/sport/basketball/nba/players/238239/jd-davison"

In Dec 2022, I used the following code to generate the list (covers_page is the url I specified above)

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(janitor)

tmp <- read_html(covers_page)

href <- as_tibble(html_attr(html_nodes(tmp, "a"), "href")) %>% 
  filter(grepl("/players/",value))
```

The output of the above is null since the list from the html_attr/html_nodes combination is not generating any of the URLs associated with the individual players on the screen.  It shows every other url node on the screen, not just these.

This worked before as I have an output file which details what I am looking for.

Has something changed in the RVEST world on how to use html_attr/html_nodes since I don't get how it is not "grabbing" these urls while grabbing the others.

Comment: Valid point.  I actually just need the url associated with each player to which I use it for another purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're encountering here is dynamicly loaded data. When the browser connects to this page it starts a background request to get the player roster and then uses javascript to update the page with this new data.

If you fire up your browser's devtools (usually F12 key) and take a look at the Network tab (xhr section):

[image]

You can see this request returns HTML data of the players:

[image]

To scrape this you need to replicate this POST request in R. Unfortunately, rvest doesn't support Post requests so you need to use alternative http client like `httr`:

```
library("httr")
# Define the endpoint URL
url <- "https://www.covers.com/sport/basketball/nba/teams/main/Boston%20Celtics/tab/roster"

# Define the JSON data to be posted
data <- list(teamId = "98", seasonId = "3996", seasonName="2022-2023", leagueName="NBA")

# Make the POST request
response <- POST(url, body = data, encode="form", add_headers("X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"))
content(response)
# then you can load the html to rvest and parse it as expected HTML
```